# React-Native change default location of iOS and Android folder

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-cli

According to the [react-native cli documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/platforms.md) we can specify custom configuration based on each platform for RN cli.
I want to change the default location of each platform folders so I added my custom `react-native.config.js` to the root of the project which you can find here:

```js
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {
      project: './example/ios/example.xcworkspace',
    },
    android: {
      sourceDir: './example/android/',
    },
  },
};
```

If I run `react-native config` in the root folder, I can see the correct configuration:

```js
{
...
  "project": {
    "ios": {
      "sourceDir": "path-to-project-directory/example/ios",
      "folder": "path-to-project-directory",
      "pbxprojPath": "path-to-project-directory/example/ios/example.xcworkspace/project.pbxproj",
      "podfile": "path-to-project-directory/example/ios/Podfile",
      "podspecPath": null,
      "projectPath": "path-to-project-directory/example/ios/example.xcworkspace",
      "projectName": "example.xcworkspace",
      "libraryFolder": "Libraries",
      "sharedLibraries": [],
      "plist": [],
      "scriptPhases": []
    },
    "android": {
      "sourceDir": "path-to-project-directory/example/android/",
      "isFlat": true,
      "folder": "path-to-project-directory",
      "stringsPath": "path-to-project-directory/example/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml",
      "manifestPath": "path-to-project-directory/example/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml",
      "buildGradlePath": "path-to-project-directory/example/android/build.gradle",
      "settingsGradlePath": "path-to-project-directory/example/android/settings.gradle",
      "assetsPath": "path-to-project-directory/example/android/app/src/main/assets",
      "mainFilePath": "path-to-project-directory/example/android/app/src/main/java/com/example/MainApplication.java",
      "packageName": "com.example",
      "packageFolder": "com/example",
      "appName": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is whenever I run `react-native run-ios` I get this error:

```sh
error iOS project folder not found. Are you sure this is a React Native project?. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

NOTE: I installed all the dependencies properly. Here is the result of the `react-native --v` command:

```sh
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.62.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, its bothering me for 2 days

Comment: @Hamid How did you resolved this ? Even I am struggling with same issue.

Answer (score 0):

`"react-native": "0.63.4"`

For iOS you need to specify the `--project-path` prop in your run script, not in react-native.config.js

Your run script should look like this:

`"ios": "react-native run-ios --project-path './<new folder>/ios'"`

But after that you need to update paths to `../../node_modules/` located modules in a lot of native files like `Podfile`, `ios/<your project name>.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`

You can check more [here](https://dev.to/iacopo87/react-native-how-to-change-the-default-folder-structure-47lf)